# Multiply two numbers entered in text fields and alert the answer using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created sum of 2 number but now want to change this code with multipy two numbers.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Jquery</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('.ck').click(function(){
                var a=parseInt($('.n1').val());
                var b=parseInt($('.n2').val());
                var c=a+b;
                alert("The sum is " + c);
            })
        })

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Enter Number 1<input type="text" class="n1"/><br/>
    Enter Number 2<input type="text" class="n2"/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Add" class="ck"/>
</body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is that a typo? Do you want to know how to muliply the numbers (i.e. `var c = a * b;`) or do you mean handling this for multiple sets of two numbers?

Comment: A simple google search would have answered this for you. Basic research is expected before asking questions here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to multiply two numbers in javascript is with the operator `*`.

Your new code would look like this, replacing `+` with `*`:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Jquery</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('.ck').click(function(){
                var a=parseInt($('.n1').val());
                var b=parseInt($('.n2').val());
                var c=a * b;
                alert("The sum is " + c);
            })
        })

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Enter Number 1<input type="text" class="n1"/><br/>
    Enter Number 2<input type="text" class="n2"/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Add" class="ck"/>
</body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Handling Multiplication**

If you want to multiply the two numbers as opposed to adding them, simply change your operator from addition `+` to multiplication `*` :

```
var c = a * b;
alert("The sum is " + c);
```

**Handling Multiple Sets of Values**

If you wanted to handle multiple sets of two numbers, then you would likely want to structure your code a bit differently. Consider using a CSS class to "group" your two values and then get your results as expected :

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').on('input', function() {
    // Find the closest set and recalculate it
    var set = $(this).closest('.set');
    // Get your values
    var n1 = parseInt(set.find('.n1').val() || 0);
    var n2 = parseInt(set.find('.n2').val() || 0);
    // Set their result
    set.find('.result').val(n1 * n2);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='set'>
  <input class='n1' />*
  <input class='n2' />=
  <input class='result' disabled />
</div>
<div class='set'>
  <input class='n1' />*
  <input class='n2' />=
  <input class='result' disabled />
</div>
```